# c# [DllImport] в методе, функция из dll без обьявления

Tags: c#, функции, dll, методы

Можно ли как-то в c# в самом методе подключить функцию из dll ?
То есть, подобную конструкцию засунуть в метод (например метод Main):

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hProcess, uint flags, StringBuilder text, out uint size);
```

Понимаю, что скорее всего метод в методе объявить не получится. Может как-то можно напрямую из dll функцию вызывать без объявления???

Comment: А зачем вам именно внутри метода, да без объявления?

Comment: есть некая программа в которой предусмотрены сценарии на c#. При создании сценария мне программа создает метод в котором я могу писать код. Выйти за пределы метода я не могу.

Comment: Если объявлять метод в методе, то компилятор ругается..

Comment: Попробуйте поставить закрывающую фигурную скобку - это выведет вас за пределы метода :-) Только не забудьте потом открыть ее обратно каким-нибудь способом.

Comment: Не поверите) Но пробовал такой способ, ругается компилятор. В программе видимо свой какой-то компилятор следит((

Comment: Я вот думаю может как-то на асемблере вставку можно сделать

Comment: В C#? Не получится.

Comment: Попробуйте через `Reflection.Emit` создать новую сборку, в ней создать этот метод, после чего его можно будет вызвать через рефлексию.

Comment: Или сделайте свою сборку, преобразуйте в массив байт, и загрузите через `Assembly.Load`.

Comment: Массив байт удобно конвертнуть в Base64, тогда его можно будет записать константой в теле вашего метода.

Comment: С такими решениями, как вы предлагаете к сожалению не сталкивался вообще. Не могу понять с полу слова( Полез штудировать гугл..                        Если это не очень трудозатратно, вы бы не могли дать рабочий пример с  `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hProcess, uint flags, StringBuilder text, out uint size);` ? Как вызвать эту функцию при помощи `Assembly.Load`

Comment: Спасибо. Все пригодилось, все получилось. Мощная штука!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Господа @Pavel Mayorov, @Lunar Whisper спасибо! Все получилось при помощи "рефлексии". [По этому линку тутор.](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.3.php)

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются на stackoverflow. Либо дополните ответ, либо давайте признаем, что это не ответ, а комментарий со спасибами.